# I want to restrict user to enter quantity which should not more then quantity in stock

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to restrict user to enter quantity which should not more then quantity in stock,iIn below JavaScript code `qty` is the quantity which I am fetching from server, and `#quantity` is the input box where I set default the value to `1`. I want that the user can not enter `quantity` more then `qty`.

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                        
    id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id_arr.split("_");
    $('#itemNo_'+id[1]).val(names[0]);
    $('#itemName_'+id[1]).val(names[1]);
    $('#packing_'+id[1]).val(names[3]);
    $('#qty_'+id[1]).val(names[4]);
    $('#quantity_'+id[1]).val(1);
    $('#discount_'+id[1]).val(0);   
    $('#price_'+id[1]).val(names[2]);
    $('#total_'+id[1]).val( 1*names[2] );
    calculateTotal();
```

hare is the HTML:

```
<td>
    <input disabled type="number" name="data[0][qty]" id="qty_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
</td>

<td>
    <input type="number" name="data[0][quantity]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
</td>
```

Comment: get the element by Id and set the max attribute using setAttribute()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `max`-attribute but this has no effect until submit.

If you want to restrict higher inputs you can do smth like this:

```
$("#quantity").keyup(function() {
  if($(this).val() > qty) {
    $(this).val(qty);
  }
});
```

this will check on every `keyup` (digit typed in) if value is higher than `qty`